# Read data in processing step spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm quite new to spring batch, while i'm doing read operation then processing where i have to read some more data from db which is conditional one which i have to do in process step.is their any way that spring can allow me to do that. else have to read all data at once in read process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring batch has nothing to do with what you want to read in process. Batch template only configures reader and writers. In the process you would read the data like any other java application. you could use the same data source they you created for reader/writer if its the same database you want to read from.